# write a point in the plane as a convex combination

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, polyhedra, convex-geometry

Suppose we have a polyhedron with vertices (extreme points) $e_1 = (4,5)$, $e_2 = (0,3)$ , $e_3=(1,2)$, $e_4=(6,0)$ and extreme direction $d_1 = (1,0)$. I want to write the vector $(10,1)$ as convex combination of the vertices and a non-negative combination of the extreme direction.

### Attempt

To see If Im understanding this material, what they are asking is that I need to find $\lambda_i$ and $\mu$ so that

$$ (10,1) = \lambda_1 (4,5) + \lambda_2 (0,3) + \lambda_3 (1,2) + \lambda_4 (6,0) + \mu (1,0) $$

satisfying the conditions $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=1$ and $\lambda_i, \mu \geq 0$

But, this would involve solve a system of 3equations and three 5 unknowns. For example, can I choose some points before doing gauss jordan elimination? for example, I can make $\mu = 9$ so that LHS becomes $(1,1)$. Is this the right approach to this problem?

Comment: perhaps you could draw a plot with all points

Comment: How do you have a polyhedron with vertices in a two-dimensional space?

Comment: @LinAlg but am I doing this problem correctly? I just wanna make sure Im understanding the concepts

Comment: @Neymar it becomes trivial after you create a plot with all points, since it will show what points to include

Comment: I tried putting the points but I dont get it, can you help me visualize it?

Comment: can you post the picture with the 4 points $e_i$ and $(10,1)$?

Comment: how about the extreme direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first look at a picture of the vertices and the point which we want to describe as a conic combination of the vertices and the extreme direction:

[image]

We observe that the $y$-coordinate of $X=(10,1)$ lies on the line between $D=(6,0)$ and $C=(1,2)$. Our extreme direction $d_1=(1,0)$ will not change the $y$-coordinate but only move a point in $x$-direction. Thus, we need to find a point with the same $y$-coordinate as $X$ and then simply add the required amount of $d_1$.

We find hence want to find the point on the line between (6,0) and (1,2) with $y$-coordinate 1. Hence, we seek $E=(\alpha,1)$ with $\lambda (6,0) +(1-\lambda)(1,2)=(\alpha,1)$ for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$. We thus need to solve for $\lambda$:

$$\lambda \cdot 0 + (1-\lambda)\cdot 2 =1$$

We obtain $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ and thus the point $E=(3.5,1)$. Now, all we have to do is add 6.5 times $d_1$ to $E$ to reach  $X=(10,1)$. In other words, we can write $X=(10,1)$ as

$$0 \cdot (4,5) +0 \cdot (0,3) +\frac{1}{2} \cdot (1,2)  +\frac{1}{2} \cdot (6,0) + 6.5 \cdot (1,0) = (10,1).$$

Since $0+0+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$ and $6.5 \ge 0$ we have indeed written $X$ as a conic combination of the $e_i$ and $d_1$.

Note that I picked points $C$ and $D$ in the picture to obtain a point with $y$-coordinate equal to 1. Instead of $C$ you could also pick any of the other points. You do, however, always need the point $D$.

Comment: the answer is so easy after you draw a picture :)

Comment: How about if we want to find a objective function $z=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$  that is bounded and has max/min at (0,6), (1,2) but not at other vertices? I was thinking to find the line between these two vertices and then use the normal to this line to be in the direction of vector $(c_1,c_2)$. is this correct?

Comment: @Neymar In this case the objective function needs to have the same slope as the line between (0,6) and (1,2). Then both vertices (and all points between the two vertices!) will be optimal.